# How to upload a .csv file to SQL server using C++

Tags: c++, sql, import, upload

I want to upload a .csv file to SQL Server to create a table. I am working with `Windows 7`, `Visual Studio 2012 Express Version`. The SQL Server is `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

May I know how can I archieve this? It could be better if anyone can come with a sample code.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
BULK 
INSERT <<TABLE NAME>>
FROM <<File name>>
WITH (
FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

See http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/20/sql-server-importing-csv-file-into-database-sql-in-sixty-seconds-018-video/

**Edit:** You will also need to create the table, but the link shows you that too.

Comment: No - this is the SQL that your C++ will need to send to the database.

Comment: I guess the alternative is to read the file line-by-line and then call an INSERT statement on the database for each one.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've tried your code, but seems there is a little problem. Would you mind my another post? Many thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277243/upload-csv-to-sql-server-using-c